# tortoisehg ignore file is not ignoring *.pyc and *.db files

Tags: django, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have this ignore file:

```
syntax: glob
*.pyc
*.db
mysite/app/migrations/**
```

it is ignoring all migration files but not pyc and db files. why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual answer is that you have already run `hg add` on the `.pyc` and `.db` files. Try running

```
$ hg locate "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"
```

to see tracked files which match your `.hgignore` patterns. Use

```
$ hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"
```

to make Mercurial forget them.

Comment: i tried also to ``forget`` pyc and db files, but it is trying to delete them in repo, will it? because forget means not to tack any more which deletes the tracked version of it, right? i cannot delete those files in repo because they are in use in prod server. i just want to ignore in local machine, is it possible?

Comment: No, you cannot both track and ignore a file. You're right that `hg forget` will delete the file when you update on the server. So you should probably do this on the server and keep a backup of the database. Then copy that database back to your development system and keep the databases ignored from then on.